# Bootstrap: setting width: auto for option makes the dropdown ugly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

All I did to a dropdown (select-options) is added a style:

```
display: inline; width: auto;
```

to make it not 100% width. So it looks like:

```
<select style="display: inline; width: auto;" 
        class="form-control" 
        name="agefrom" 
        id="agefrom">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
</select>
```

with the newest Firefox, the border gets trimmed:[image]

How could I prevent this?

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 2):

Change display: inline to inline-block

```
<select style="display: inline-block; width: auto;" class="form-control" name="agefrom" id="agefrom">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
```

Comment: The question is a statement. "Adding this CSS to this element makes it ugly". It's a `true` statement. What question exactly are you answering?

Comment: how avoid it making it ugly? :)

Comment: It's a bad question, but you can clearly see that he wants the border to be "not trimmed" :) ... be more helpful

Comment: I highly recommend asking the question instead of letting people guess it.

Comment: Agree, use the "review" function to help him out! :)

Answer (score 2):

Select box whitespace is added by the browser's rendering engine.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms#Dealing_with_the_select_nightmare

and

I recommend this way to make inline form

- Add class .form-inline to the `<form>` element

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp

Comment: yea, right, in the meantime I figured it out. I thought I had to hack the bootstrap